# Failed to hit an API. Wrong signature type

Tags: laravel, api, ssl, curl, guzzle

i try to hit an API with Laravel via Guzzle but i keep get the same error :

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 35: error:0A000172:SSL routines::wrong signature type
```

I have tried all the solution in the internet like set verify to false :

```
$client = new Client([
        'headers' => [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ],
        'verify' => false
    ]);
```

or setting down the SSL version :

```
$client = new Client([
        'headers' => [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ],
        'curl' => array(
            CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2
        )
    ]);
```

but i have no luck. I keep get the same error message.

Comment: Did you update the cURL package?

Comment: yes, my cURL package at the newest version